# Use mdf file that was created with visual studio 2008 on another computer

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

I created a database with Visual Studio 2008 and I have a file in `c:\data.mdf` how I can use it on another computer?

I can't use this database, I installed SQL Server Express 2005 - that install is on the first machine.

Answer (score 1):

To move a database from one location to another,

you need to

**1. Detach from your source database server:** Since you are using Visual Studio 2008 on your source machine, go to Server Explorer - Right click on Databases - Click on Detach.

**2. Copy MDF & LDF file to target machine**

**3. Attach MDF file to your destination database server:** Repeat step 1 on target machine's SQL Server, and Instead of Detach - Choose Attach and select the relevant MDF file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not access an mdf file directly, you always go through the server.

To 'tell' Sql Server about the database:

```
Goto the Object Explorer window.
Right click Databases.
Select Attach...
Then Add...
```